# Inserting Dataframe into MS SQLServer DB using python.to_sql() with SQLAlchemy takes too much time

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, performance, sqlalchemy

### **Background:**

I am creating a platform using python, where a user (layman) will be able to upload the data in the database on their own.
The user will select an excel file and the python will create multiple dataframes that will be stored in their each respective table on MS SQL Server in a Database.

### **Situation:**

I am creating **12 different dataframes** using the excel file and storing it in the MS SQL Database. The file has approximately 50k rows and about 150 columns (16mb file in total). **The code works perfectly fine but is not time efficient** since it takes approximately **2-3 mins** just to upload these 12 frames to the database. I did a test run on a bigger file (Approx 50mb) and the time it took to upload these 12 frames in the database was **7 minutes**

### Where I need support:

Is there any way I can speed up this process of storing the data to the database? Ideally it should only be a matter of seconds and not minutes. I have tried the following libraries and got the results as follows.

**Connection String and Data load in DataFrames:**

```
#Connection String
connection_string = f"""
    DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};
    SERVER={{{SERVER_NAME}}};
    DATABASE={{{DATABASE_NAME}}};
    uid=XYZ;
    pwd=XYZ;
    Trust_Connection=yes;
    ColumnEncryption=Enabled;
    """

#Connection to Database
params=urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params), fast_executemany=True)
con=engine.connect()


#DataFrame 1 to be stored in DB table_1 of DB
df_Addr = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = "Address_Details")

#DataFrame 2 to be stored in DB table_2 of DB
df_Bank = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = "Bank_Details")

.
.
.

#DataFrame 12 to be stored in DB table_12 of DB
df_N = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = "N_Details")
```

***Option 1:*** : Using SQLAlchemy

```
#Saving Frame 1 in Table 1
saving_query_Address='DQ_Raw_Address'
df_Addr.to_sql(saving_query_Address,engine,schema="dbo",if_exists='append',index=False, chunksize = 5000, dtype={'NAME1': sa.types.NVARCHAR(length=100), 'CITY1': sa.types.NVARCHAR(length=100), 'STREET': sa.types.NVARCHAR(length=100)})


#Saving Frame 2 in Table 2
saving_query_Bank='DQ_Raw_Bank'
df_Bank.to_sql(saving_query_Bank,engine,schema="dbo",if_exists='append',index=False, chunksize = 5000, dtype={'_COMMENT':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'_ACTION_CODE':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'SOURCE_ID':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'BKVID':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'PARTNER':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'BANKS':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'IBAN':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),'ACCOUNT_ID':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=50),'CHECK_DIGIT':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=50),'ACCOUNT_TYPE':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=50),'BP_EEW_BUT0BK':sa.types.VARCHAR(length=50)})

#The logic follows for the remaining 10 Tables as well with the same settings.

#Total Time Taken: 130 seconds
```

***Option 2:** : Using PyODBC*

```
#Saving Frame 1 in Table 1
saving_query_Address='DQ_Raw_Address'
insert_to_tbl = f"INSERT INTO {saving_query_Address} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(insert_to_tbl, df_Addr.values.tolist())
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
                
#Saving Frame 2 in Table 2
saving_query_Bank='DQ_Raw_Bank'
insert_to_tmp_tbl_stmt = f"INSERT INTO {saving_query_Bank} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(insert_to_tmp_tbl_stmt, df_Bank.values.tolist())
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
                
#The logic follows for the remaining 10 Tables as well with the same settings.

#Total Time Taken: 200 seconds
```

***Note:*** I have tried loading the data as csv in the dataframe but no improvement so far. Cannot execute BULK INSERT query because do not have Bulk Admin rights on SQLServer. Also, I need to use VPN to connect to the server.

***Versions Used:***

Pandas: 1.5.0
,PyODBC: 4.0.34
,SQLALCHEMY: 1.4.42

I hope I made the issue clear.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have found that in some cases [this method](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205) can be faster than `.to_sql( … ,method=None)` (the default) with `fast_executemany=True`

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking to suggest that it is remotely possible for your task to complete in "a matter of seconds and not minutes"? VPN connections are often quite slow, so any such benchmarking should be done over your particular VPN.

Comment: Status update: I tested with a Local DB and it took like 4-5 seconds to fully load all the frames into the database. What should i consider with the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, The issue was fixed using the following two approaches.

**1.** Reading the dataframe using pd.read_excel() was taking approx ~10 seconds to load a single frame. This can be cut by using pd.read_csv() from 10 seconds to merely half a second.

**2.** For storing purposes, I figured that TurbODBC works best for me to load all 12 frames in merely 20 seconds. Here is the link for TurbODBC that helped me for storing the data in a database in a timely fashion.

https://erickfis.medium.com/etl-process-with-turbodbc-1d19ed71510e

I hope this helps someone facing similar issues.